# Split elements of a list based on character

Tags: python, list, split

Hi I have a list of elements which some elements have a ',' in between that I wish to split into seperate elements
Ex:

```
['Agrigento',
 ' Tal Andar, Regie Curie',
 ' Landar ta il Geuenie',
 ' Landar ta il Guedi,  Casali Bisibud',
 'Aragonia',
 'Athene']
```

should look like:

```
 ['Agrigento',
     ' Tal Andar',
     ' Regie Curie',
     ' Landar ta il Geuenie',
     ' Landar ta il Guedi',  
     ' Casali Bisibud',
     'Aragonia',
     'Athene']
```

Any idea how it is possible. I want to keep both elements of the split

Comment: Did you intentionally keep the single leading space, but collapse the double leading space to a single one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [list-comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) with the standard scheme for [flattening arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python):

```
lst = ['Agrigento',
 ' Tal Andar, Regie Curie',
 ' Landar ta il Geuenie',
 ' Landar ta il Guedi,  Casali Bisibud',
 'Aragonia',
 'Athene']

lst = [x for y in lst for x in y.split(',')]
print(lst)  # -> ['Agrigento', ' Tal Andar', ' Regie Curie', ' Landar ta il Geuenie', ' Landar ta il Guedi', '  Casali Bisibud', 'Aragonia', 'Athene']
```

---

Note: We are taking advantage of the fact that splitting a string that does not contain the character used as a delimiter returns the same string in a list:

```
>> 'a'.split('b')
['a']
```

As a result, the flattening meets no obstacles. For more info, see [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

---

Finally, as @tobias says, if you want to get rid of the spaces in the front and back of the names, you can use the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method. Simply modify the above comprehension to the one given below.

```
lst = [x.strip() for y in lst for x in y.split(',')]
print(lst)  # -> ['Agrigento', 'Tal Andar', 'Regie Curie', 'Landar ta il Geuenie', 'Landar ta il Guedi', 'Casali Bisibud', 'Aragonia', 'Athene']
```

Comment: Might add a not about `x.strip()` as well, although OP is a bit inconsistent on whether to remove the spaces or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = ['Agrigento', ' Tal Andar, Regie Curie', ' Landar ta il Geuenie', ' Landar ta il Guedi,  Casali Bisibud', 'Aragonia', 'Athene']
result = []

for elem in elements:
    if ',' in elem:
        result.extend([s for s in element.split(',')])
    else:
        result.append(elem)

print(result)
```